# How to extract multiple mailing addresses from PDF file using pdftotext

Tags: regex, bash, pdf, grep, pipe

I am using `pdftotext` in a bash script, trying to extract the names and addresses from PDF postage labels.

An example PDF file:

```
Delivered By:

1st Class
Postage on Account GB

First Last
HouseName
Street
Town
County
Postcode

Customer Reference: 12400 / 203 1

32224983765

RETURN TO: MyName,
DoorNumber, Street, Town,
City, Postcode, Country

121-0434 905 20200-000 6190 C228

Delivered By:

1st Class
Postage on Account GB

First Last
HouseNumber
Street
Town
Postcode

Customer Reference: 12401 / 200 1

32224286536

RETURN TO: MyName,
DoorNumber, Street, Town,
City, Postcode, Country

121-0434 905 20200-000 6190 C414
```

Please note:

- The addresses do not have a fixed length ie. some consist of only 4 lines, and I have seen some with up to 6 lines.
- The number of addresses in the PDF file will not be known in advance.

So far, I have just got:

```
pdftotext label.pdf - | grep -A10 "Postage on Account GB" | tail -n+3 | head -n -3
```

The `-` avoids creating a file. The `grep -A10` outputs the first 10 lines from the match `"Postage on Account GB"`. The `tail -n+3` removes the match and next line. The `head -n -3` removes the last 3 lines. That works fine when there's only one address in the file consisting of 6 lines, but I'm stuck when it comes to multiple addresses and with different lengths.

Put simply, I would like to extract the data from after the blank line after `Postage on Account GB`, until the line before the next blank line. Then format the output so that addresses are comma delimited and each on a new line, such as:

```
First Last, HouseName, Street, Town, County, Postcode
First Last, HouseNumber, Street, Town, Postcode
```

Comment: The problem with mailing addresses is they don't follow a fixed pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

In the light of your comments, I have updated my answer as follows:

```
pdftotext file.pdf - | perl -00 -wnl -e 'BEGIN{$a=$r=0} if($a){($add=$_)=~tr/\n/,/; $r=1; $a=0; next} if($r){printf "%s,%s\n",$_,$add;$r=0} $a=1 if m/Postage on Account/;'
```

One record is read each time through the loop - a record is separated by blank lines above and below because of `-00`. At the start, I set `$a` and `$r` flags to zero, meaning we are not looking at an address nor a reference. If we are looking at an address, I translate all newlines into commas and note that we are now looking for a reference. If we find a reference, we print it and the saved address and note that we are no longer looking at an address or a reference. If we find the string "Postage on Account", we note that we are now expecting an address to follow.

**Sample Output**

```
Customer Reference: 12400 / 203 1,First Last,HouseName,Street,Town,County,Postcode
Customer Reference: 12401 / 200 1,First Last,HouseNumber,Street,Town,Postcode
```

**Original Answer**

I think I'd go with Perl in paragraph mode:

```
pdftotext file - | perl -00 -wnl -e 'BEGIN{$p=1} if($p==1){tr/\n/,/;print;$p=0}; $p=1 if /Postage/'
```

The `-00` sets Perl in *paragraph mode* treating each blank line delimited block as a paragraph. The `BEGIN{...}` sets the print flag (`$p`) so the first line gets printed. On subsequent paragraphs, when the print flag is set, the newlines get changed into spaces with `tr` and the paragraph gets printed and the flag reset. Finally, whenever we see the word `Postage` we set the print flag.

Comment: I now have a working Raspberry Pi again - apologies for the delay. @mark-setchell Your solution is very close, though it outputs "Delivered By:" and a blank line when it first starts, and after each address it also prints a blank line. How can I remove those two features? I also have a new requirement to put the Customer Reference number at the start of each line, so in the first example it would start `12400 / 203 1, First Last, HouseName, Street, Town, County, Postcode` - is that possible?

Comment: Please have another look - I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 pdftotext filename.pdf - |sed -n '/Postage on Account GB/,/Customer Reference:/{/Postage on Account GB/!{/Customer Reference:/!p}}' |grep . |tr '\n' ',' |sed 's/,$//g' |sed "s/Postcode/&\n/g" |sed 's/^,//g'
First Last,HouseName,Street,Town,County,Postcode
First Last,HouseNumber,Street,Town,Postcode
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply - I still have a system boot failure to resolve before I can try your suggestion ([“Error: The file system is bigger than its volume!”](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54763/raspberry-boot-failure-error-the-file-system-is-bigger-than-its-volume)), however I'm not sure if your code will work because where you've taken "Postcode" in `sed "s/Postcode/&\n/g"` - "Postcode" was just a substitute I used for the purposes of the example, in real situations this field will show the customer's actual postcode which will always be different. Thanks.

Comment: Show  us  what  you  want  to  replace,  will  try  to  modify command as per your  need.